# Sentence meaning - idiom?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I've recently come accross a sentence:

> I admit the woman drudges in the home, as a man might drudge at the Cathedral of Amiens or drudge behind a gun at Trafalgar.

I'm wondering whether "behind a gun" means more or less "to carry a gun". And whether Trafalgar stands here for the Trafalgar Square??

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have a source for this.? What's it from? When was it written?

Comment: And I suspect *Trafalgar* refers to the Battle of Trafalger https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Trafalgar

Answer (score 3):

Here the word "drudge" means "toil", or "do hard work": http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drudge. It's not so commonly used these days (so I'd imagine that this is a relatively old quote) but still makes sense ('drudgery' is still in relatively common usage, at least in the UK).

From the context of "behind a gun", I'd assume that the author is speaking about the Battle of Trafalgar, rather than about Trafalgar Square. Since that was a naval battle, "gun" would be referring to a ship's cannon rather than some kind of handheld weapon. So another way of putting the last part of the example would be to change

> drudge behind a gun at Trafalgar

to

> work behind a cannon during the Battle of Trafalgar.

Comment: +1 [Here](http://www.artvalue.fr/photos/auction/0/44/44502/cooper-john-1942-united-kingdo-the-middle-gun-deck-on-h-m-s-v-2071844.jpg)'s a painting, from Christie's, of men working the guns at Trafalgar.

Comment: Right.  Admittedly, one would not ordinarily speak of "drudging behind a gun". The word choice is intentionally forced in furtherance of an implicit argument.